# Cider debug -- how to evaluate stuff while debugging

Tags: clojure, cider

Cider debug [instructions](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider/blob/master/doc/debugging.md) tell me I can press `e` to evaluate something while debugging.  This gives me a little one-line space in Emacs mini-buffer at the bottom.

Is there a way to switch to the full REPL while in the middle of
debugging a function, with access to all the locals, etc.?  Currently
the REPL is hung/frozen while debugging.  I'm thinking of something in
the style of how PyCharm or Matlab allow full REPL while in the middle of something.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear that the jacked-in REPL is tied up during debugging.
But there are a few options available through the debugger that may
give you nearly as much as you'd get out of the REPL.  A handy one is
to *in`j`ect* a new value for the result you're about to produce.
So you're actually changing the data on-the-fly.

You can inspect the full list of local vars with `l`.  Then see more
about a var with *ins`p`ect* and specifying which.

You can also *`e`val* to enter an **arbitrary expression** just like
you would in the REPL (as you've mentioned).  That seems to be a
single-line full REPL, with history, editing, etc.  Is there something
you'd want to do in the REPL that you can't do with `e` or discover
with `l` or `p`?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I find really frustrating is that I can't edit a function while the debugger is stoped at the said function, then edit it and re run it with the initial arguments. In cider, if you try to edit a function being debugged, emacs will open the bebugger in a new buffer with the original code. Alternatively, you have the `e` command that evals things in the minibuffer, which I don't think is a great experience. The closest I came to this is the following:

Imagine you have some function that crashes and you need to debug:

```
(defn some-fn 
  [complex-data more-data]
  ; block of code with some bug
)
```

I'll create atoms in the namespace and set the value inside the given function:

```
(def c (atom nil))
(def d (atom nil))

(defn some-fn 
  [complex-data more-data]
  (reset! c complex-data)
  (reset! d more-data)
  ; block of code with some bug
)
```

Then I'l just iterate on `some-fn` using the args I now have available in the namespace.

```
(some-fn @c @d)
```

I think it's a much better approach than using the eval command and the minibuffer from the cider debugger.